# How to start Eclipse from Ubuntu on startup

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, ubuntu

I want to start Eclipse on startup of Ubuntu 18.
Because I need the variables from .bashrc I need to start it from the terminal. Manually starting eclipse from the terminal works. But it won't start on startup when I use a script.

I have a python3 script running on startup of Ubuntu 18.
I want to start Eclipse from the command line using this script. Eclipse won't run and I don't get any error messages.

Manually starting eclipse:

```
nohup eclipse > /dev/null
```

My script:

```py
import os
import subprocess

#bash_command = 'nohup eclipse > /dev/null'
bash_command = 'eclipse'

proc = subprocess.Popen(bash_command, shell=True, stdout =subprocess.PIPE)
bash_output  = str(proc.communicate()[0])

fo = open("output.txt", "w+")
fo.write(bash_output)
fo.close()
```

I have tried the following as well:

```py
bash_output = os.popen(bash_command,'r',1)
```

```py
bash_output = subprocess.run([bash_command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The script runs, but eclipse doesn't start. I get an empty output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The problem was the location of eclipse. It was installed in the home directory.
The solution was to add this path to ~/.profile and to export my toolchain paths.